# How to make a big shell script in a single line shell script in json document?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I am working on Python along with bash shell script. I need to execute shell script from the Python script. I am successfully able to do that.. I need to have a shell script in a single line in a JSON String..

Below is an example which is working fine for a simple shell script which I have made it in a JSON document...

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9], "sp": [1,2,4,6,8]}'
jj = json.loads(jsonData)

os.putenv( 'jj3', ' '.join( str(v) for v in jj['pp']  ) )
os.putenv( 'jj4', ' '.join( str(v) for v in jj['sp']  ) )

jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \\n echo Hello World \\n "}'

j = json.loads(jsonStr)

shell_script = j['script']

print "start"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print "Shell script gave some error"
    print stdout
else:
    print "end"
    print stdout
```

Now I have a below shell script which I need to represent it in a single line in a JSON document as I have done for above Hello World use case..

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

readonly PRIMARY=/tech01/primary
readonly SECONDARY=/tech02/secondary
readonly LOCATION=(machineA machineB)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot
HOSTNAME=$hostname

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

length1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[0]} "ls '$dir1' | wc -l")
length2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[1]} "ls '$dir2' | wc -l")

echo $length1
echo $length2

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ] && [ "$length1" -gt 0 ] && [ "$length2" -gt 0 ]
then
    rm -rf $PRIMARY/*
    rm -rf $SECONDARY/*
    for el in $primary_partition
    do
        scp david@${LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/weekly_8880_"$el"_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@${LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/weekly_8880_"$el"_5.data $PRIMARY/.
    done
fi
```

I have made the above shell script in a single line JSON document like this but this doesn't work and I always get an error

```
jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \n set -e \n readonly PRIMARY=/tech01/primary \n readonly SECONDARY=/tech02/secondary \n readonly LOCATION=(machineA machineB) \n readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot \n HOSTNAME=$hostname \n dir1=$(ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" david@${LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 \"$MAPPED_LOCATION\"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1) \n dir2=$(ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" david@${LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 \"$MAPPED_LOCATION\"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1) \n echo $dir1 \n echo $dir2 \n length1=$(ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" david@${LOCATION[0]} \"ls \'$dir1\' | wc -l\") \n length2=$(ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" david@${LOCATION[1]} \"ls \'$dir2\' | wc -l\") \n echo $length1 \n echo $length2 \n if [ \"$dir1\" = \"$dir2\" ] && [ \"$length1\" -gt 0 ] && [ \"$length2\" -gt 0 ] \n then \n rm -rf $PRIMARY/* \n rm -rf $SECONDARY/* \n for el in $primary_partition \n do \n scp david@${LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_\"$el\"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@${LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_\"$el\"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. \n done \n fi"}'
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
ValueError: Invalid control character
```

Can anyone help me what wroing I am doing? And what's the right way to make above shell script in a Single line JSON document?

**UPDATE:-**

There is another twist into this which I thought its worth mentioning..

I need to store this single line shell script data in a Zookeeper node. So for Hello World shell script example case, I am storing by using the following code. I am using Curator library to write into Zookeeper.

```
client.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().forPath("/be/wf/error1/v1/step1", "{\"description\":\"Hello World 1.\", \"script\":\"#!/bin/bash \\n set -e \\n echo Hello World 1 \\n\"}".getBytes());
```

And then I have my Python program to read the Zookeeper node data and then execute the shell script by extracting from the script tag..

Now I tried representing the same script as mentioned in the answer, in the above format, and my Eclipse started giving compilation errors on the string. So how do I represent the shell script as given in the answer in the above..

I guess I really need a JSON so that I can store it properly in Zookeeper node and then my Python program can read the same JSON data from the node and execute the shell script from the script tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider whether you really need JSON. In your example code, you create a JSON string and then immediately decode it into a Python dict. Would it be simpler to just use a dict directly?

The problem with your current string is that you're not escaping your quotation marks properly. To avoid confusing multi-level escaping, use a triple-quoted string to represent the shell script and `json.dumps` to convert a dict into a JSON string:

```
import json
jsonstr = json.dumps({"script": """\
#!/bin/bash
set -e

readonly PRIMARY=/tech01/primary
readonly SECONDARY=/tech02/secondary
readonly LOCATION=(machineA machineB)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot
HOSTNAME=$hostname

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

length1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[0]} "ls '$dir1' | wc -l")
length2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${LOCATION[1]} "ls '$dir2' | wc -l")

echo $length1
echo $length2

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ] && [ "$length1" -gt 0 ] && [ "$length2" -gt 0 ]
then
    rm -rf $PRIMARY/*
    rm -rf $SECONDARY/*
    for el in $primary_partition
    do
        scp david@${LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/weekly_8880_"$el"_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@${LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/weekly_8880_"$el"_5.data $PRIMARY/.
    done
fi"""})
```

Alternatively, you could put the shell script in its own file and open the file to read the string from it.

Comment: Thank You. It might be a silly question to ask..  In a JSON document if I have triple quoted string, then it is a valid JSON document?

Comment: @SSH -- No, JSON doesn't recognize triple quoted strings.  That's a feature of Python.  However, you can create a python dictionary using triple quoted strings and dump that into a JSON file just fine.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to propose.  +1

Comment: And also can you show me where I am decoding it to Python Dictionary as well? I just started with Python so there are few things I still need to memorize?

Comment: @SSH: That's the `json.loads` call.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with one minor detail.. I am not sure how do I use your suggestion to store the data in Zookeeper node correctly so that my Python agent can read that data and execute the shell script correctly..

Comment: @SSH: I can't tell what the problem is from what you've shown. You should be able to use the string returned from `json.dumps` in the place you previously would have used a literal string. It's probable that you accidentally deleted a character or mismatched your quotes or parentheses or something like that.

Comment: Ok.. Now what I did is that.. I represented my shell script in the triple quoted string as you told me.. And then at the end I printed out like this `print jsonstr` which shows me the JSON String that I can use on my console. And I use the same JSON string that printed out to write into Zookeeper node.. And then use my Python agent to read that JSON document and execute the shell script.. And this time I got this error `/bin/sh: 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
`. I am going to update my question accordingly which will for sure give you something that can tell me what wrong I am doing.

Comment: @SSH: Is `readonly LOCATION=(machineA machineB)` valid bash syntax? I don't actually know bash scripting, so I can't tell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44682/discussion-between-ssh-and-user2357112)